# Why am I requested to log in again before I can post a question even though I have logged in

Tags: support

I had not learned of Super User community until two days ago when my question was migrated from Software community to Super User community. (I did not remember that I had joined in this community 10 months ago, I am very sorry.)

Ok then, I am so surprised that people here are nice and trying their best to help. But I found that whenever I tried to post a new question here, I would be requested to log in again before I could post it. It was strange to me since I had already logged in to Stack Exchange community.

I have no idea why this happened.

Answer (score 2):

This does not make a lot of sense. 
Once you ***join*** a Stack Exchange community,
you are a member forever (well, almost forever),
and you joined Super User [ten months ago](https://superuser.com/users/408673/kitty?tab=profile),
so you shouldn’t be having a problem with that. 
And, once you login to any Stack Exchange community,
you are automatically logged in to all the communities
that you have ever joined — in that browser session. 
Of course, if you log out, or switch browsers, you must login again,
but what you describe should not have happened.

Next time you’re in this situation, look at the top bar. 
If it shows your gravatar (account picture) and your stats, like this:

[image]

you’re logged in, and should not be asked to log in again. 
But if you see this:

[image]

then you’re not logged in.  (Be sure to select “log in”,
because “sign up” means “create a *new* account”,
and you don’t want to do that.)

P.S. Thanks for saying that we’re nice!

Comment: Thank you for the help, G-Man. Immediately after I had logged in Stackexchange community, I noticed that there was a new message in the Inbox, so I clicked the message and it directed me to this post. I saw your answer but when I tried to add this message (in the comment)  to you, I was requested to log in again. I do not know why.

Comment: Well, I don't understand why that's happening — there might be a problem with your system. Have you tried this in multiple browsers? Have you tried it on another computer?